# Installing wireless usb adapter driver in desktop computer on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb

**[http://www.amazon.com/LB-LINK-Wireless-USB-Adapter-BL-WN155A/dp/B00WI33SGU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WI33SGU)**

This is the wireless usb adapter i bought.I got cd with linux drivers on it.
But i don't know how to install the driver in ubuntu 14.04 because i am new to linux.Can any one help me.Here is the link to the driver and most importantly i don't have internet connection.

**http://download.cukii.com/lblink/drivers/WIFI-FE-2(Other%20Driver).zip**